# Re-filling entire paragraph automatically with auto-fill-mode?

Tags: emacs, word-wrap, dot-emacs

**Motivation:** Using the defaults, Auto Fill mode seems not as useful as I might
have hoped:  If I insert a sentence in the middle of a paragraph, only the current
line is re-filled.  When I insert a sentence, I want the entire paragraph to be re-filled.

**Question:** How can I set `auto-fill-function` (or perhaps
`normal-auto-fill-function`) in my .emacs
file so that the paragraph is re-filled whenever a single line overflows?
I tried setting it to `fill-paragraph`, but then I cannot insert *any* spaces at the end of a paragraph (e.g., to add another word).

**More details:** I primarily use Auto Fill mode in the AUCTeX major mode for LaTeX.

The built-in Emacs documentation for `auto-fill-mode` states:

> When `auto-fill-mode` is on, the `auto-fill-function` variable is
>   non-`nil`.
>
> The value of `normal-auto-fill-function` specifies the function to use
>   for `auto-fill-function` when turning Auto Fill mode on.

The documentation for the `normal-auto-fill-function` variable
says that it is the function to use for `auto-fill-function` if Auto Fill mode is
turned on, and that the initial value is `do-auto-fill`.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to try `refill-mode`.  But in general, it's just tricky to make such a feature work well.  Another approach is to only do the refill as part of the redisplay (i.e. without affecting the buffer's actual content).  For that, try setting `word-wrap` or enabling `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I will try those modes.

Answer (score 1):

For LaTeX files you can try (requires AUCTeX)

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                  (setq auto-fill-function 'LaTeX-fill-paragraph)))
```

but use it with caution.

Comment: This works great for editing inside a paragraph, but refuses to let me insert a space (to start a new word) at the end of a paragraph. I'm having better luck with `(setq auto-fill-function (lambda () (if (looking-at "\n") (do-auto-fill) (LaTeX-fill-paragraph))))`